# Apply ListFormat to First column of numerous of tables in Document Through VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to make a sub procedure that can go through numerous of tables and make a list in each cell of the first column. I already have the ListTemplate defined. I've tried using

```
Selection.Tables(tabNum).Columns(1).Select
Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
        ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _
        True, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
        wdWord10ListBehavior
Selection.collaspe
```

Which works for the first Table, but then gives a "Requested member of the collection does not exist" for the second table.

I want to try to not use Selection, but I can't find a way, other than increment each cell in the table, to do it(Which takes an hour for 21 Tables through this way versus 7 seconds per table by using the selection way).

I have many tables with many rows that I want a list for, so I'm trying to make it as efficient as possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

U can loop through all tables and apply the format for each table of the loop.

Something like:

```
Sub test()

Dim tb As ListObject
Dim sht As Worksheet


For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

    For Each tb In sht.ListObjects

        tb.Columns(1).Select
        Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
        ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _
        True, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
        wdWord10ListBehavior
        Selection.collaspe

    Next tb

Next sht

End sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To stay away from the Selection method in Word, use Ranges. Here is code that I believe will work to your specifications.

```
Sub UpdateTables()
Dim doc As Word.Document, rng As Word.Range
Dim tbl As Word.Table, rw As Word.Row, cRng As Word.Range
Set doc = ActiveDocument
Set rng = doc.Content
For Each tbl In rng.Tables
    For Each rw In tbl.rows
        Set cRng = rw.Cells(1).Range
        cRng.MoveEnd Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, Count:=-1
        cRng.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
            ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _
            True, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
            wdWord10ListBehavior
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to function by looping each table, then each row in each table. It's similar to the method I made that loops each cell in a column which took over an hour for 21 tables. Thanks for the input though.